# MenuItem cannot be cast to com.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView

Tags: java, android

I have an app that uses a recycler view with code integrated from google's sample recycler view with native express ads github. When I launch the app, the ad loads at the top, but when I start scrolling I get an exception in my adapter.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: dstudios.project.Utilities.MenuItem
>   cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView

The code in my adapter looks like the following:

```
case NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE:

        default:
            NativeExpressAdViewHolder nativeExpressHolder =
                    (NativeExpressAdViewHolder) holder;
            NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) mData.get(position);
            ViewGroup adCardView = (ViewGroup) nativeExpressHolder.itemView;
            // The NativeExpressAdViewHolder recycled by the RecyclerView may be a different
            // instance than the one used previously for this position. Clear the
            // NativeExpressAdViewHolder of any subviews in case it has a different
            // AdView associated with it, and make sure the AdView for this position doesn't
            // already have a parent of a different recycled NativeExpressAdViewHolder.
            if (adCardView.getChildCount() > 0) {
                adCardView.removeAllViews();
            }
            if (adView.getParent() != null) {
                ((ViewGroup) adView.getParent()).removeView(adView);
            }

            // Add the Native Express ad to the native express ad view.
            adCardView.addView(adView);
```

The exception is happening on this line:

```
                NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) mData.get(position);
```

The list that is use is declared in the adapter at the top:

```
private final List<Object> mData;
```

And my menuitem class looks like this:

```
public class MenuItem {
    public String Name;
    public String UCPC;
    public String QR;
    public String URL;
    public String Image;
    public String Company;
    public String Reviews;
    public String CreatedAt;
    public String CountryOrigin;
    public String UpdatedAt;
    public String Lineage;
    public String Genetics;
    public String Countries;


    public MenuItem(String name, String UCPC, String Genetics, String URL,
                    String image, String updatedAt, String QR) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.UCPC = UCPC;
        this.Genetics = Genetics;
        this.URL = URL;
        this.Image = image;
        this.UpdatedAt = updatedAt;
        this.QR = QR;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getUCPC() {
        return UCPC;
    }

    public String getGenetics() {
        return Genetics;
    }

    public String getURL() {
        return URL;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return Image;
    }
    public String updatedAt() {
        return UpdatedAt;
    }
    public String QR() {
        return QR;
    }
}
```

I have no clue why it's throwing the exception and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ClassCastExceptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) occur when you're trying to cast an object to a class that it is not an instance of.

In your case, `mData.get(position)` returns an object of type `MenuItem`. And you're trying to cast it to a `NativeExpressAdView` - hence, the following error occurs :-

> java.lang.ClassCastException: dstudios.project.Utilities.MenuItem
>   cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView

So, I don't know how you've structured your data, but all you need to do to solve this is to make sure that `mData.get(position)` returns an object of type `NativeExpressAdView`.

Comment: Thank you. I added the ad setup to the async task and that loaded the data then added the ads.